# {{#each}} tags across multiple tables

Tags: meteor

I'm not doing something very performant. I've got a number of tables that need filling in from a collection like this (just two are shown):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s3" id="change-code" style="background-color: #22313f; color: #fff; height: 150px; position: relative; top: -100px">
  <p class="grid-title">code:</p>
  {{#each demographic}}
  <div style="font-size: 5.0em; line-height: 100%; font-weight: 600">{{Code}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>

<div class="col s4" id="name-address-change" style="background-color: #1e8bc3; color: #fff; height: 200px">
  <p class="grid-title">Name/Address:</p>
  {{#each demographic}}
  <p>{{FullName}}</p>
  <p>{{Address}}</p>
  <p>{{City}}, {{State}} {{Zip}} {{CountryCode}}</p>
  <p>{{Country}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>

<div class="col s5" id="contact-change" style="background-color: #34495e; color: #fff; height: 200px">
  <p class="grid-title">Contact:</p>
  {{#each demographic}}
  <p>Hphone: {{Hphone}}</p>
  <p>Cphone: {{Cphone}}</p>
  <p>SN: {{Email}}</p>
  <p>SS: {{StudentEmail}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

It looks like every time the {{#each demographic}} is invoked, it reruns the template helper, and queries the collection again:

```
Template.clientGrid.helpers({

  'demographic': function () {
  var fullNameD = Session.get('clientName');
  return Demographic.find({ FullName: fullNameD});
},

  'programs': function () {
  var fullNameP = Session.get('clientName');
  return Programs.find({ FullName: fullNameP});
  }
});
```

It seems like the helper only needs to run one time. How can I do that?

Comment: The helper is re-running because you've invoked it multiple times. Please note that it's running that query against minimongo in your browser memory and will thus be very fast. Your server is not being hit for each invocation. There's little point optimizing this out.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware why it was re-running, but just didn't know if there was a better way.